# PHP: find all filename with extension in a text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find all filename with extension in a text.
for exemple:

```
<roottag>
 <step>first element using file_text.txt</step>
 <step>server.sql</step>
 <step>using another.txt file</step>
 <txt> elements other.this </txt>
</roottag>
```

I would like to extract all filename with extension:

```
file_text.txt
server.sql
another.txt
other.this
```

Did you have any idea with preg_match_all?

Thanks in advance

Cris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$preg = '/(\w+\.\w{2,4})/';
preg_match_all($preg, $text);
```

Comment: it's better to remove `{2,4}`, it won't work for extensions like `.aacdb`

Comment: @Death do You know some widely used file extension that consists of 5 letters?

Comment: @adamdesign yea, they're like one of the most common out there, right ;-) Ive never encountered them in my life so far :)

Comment: @manWe And what about filenames with dashes or other legal characters?

Comment: @tomasr then it would be trivial to change it to accept anything 
`$preg = '/(.+?)\.\w{2,4}/'` or `$preg = '/([^\.]+)\.\w{2,4}/'`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z_]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/', $string , $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

would match files in you string $string and put an array of matches in $arr.

The regexp string is /[a-z_]+.[a-z]{2,4}/ and it assumes that you are searching for files that are composed by a first letter string that can contain underscores, followed by a point and an extension that can be min 2 char long and max 4 char long.

You can test your regexp string [RegExp Tester](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

so you can add some more rules in the match.